# Fix corupt external usb disk

Tags: boot, partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk, disk-image

Used win32diskimager (img to usb utility) to copy a Ubuntu to a external 500GB HDD and now it's corrupt (at least for windows), Ubuntu booted ok from it like nothing ever happened.

The problem is I have (had) important files there and I wish to recover them.

What tools are available for file recovery ? 
How much will it take to recover the files? What is the fastest way?
What to expect?

thank you .

## Methods tried:

I started *TestDisk 7.0-WIP, Data Recovery Utility* and here is the output so far:

```
TestDisk 7.0-WIP, Data Recovery Utility, October 2013 Christophe
GRENIER <grenier a t cgsecurity.org> http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sdb - 500 GB / 465 GiB - CHS 60801 255 63 Analyse cylinder 
4672/60800: 07%     

check_FAT: Unusual media descriptor (0xf8!=0xf0) Warning: number of
heads/cylinder mismatches 64 (FAT) != 255 (HD) Warning: number of
sectors per track mismatches 32 (FAT) != 63 (HD)   FAT12              
111 130 44 

111 202 51       4544 [NO NAME]
```

took about 2 hours to get to 7% ( and I accidentally stooped it )

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'gpart' and 'gparted' tools to recover data from hard-disks.

1. Install gpart and gparted.

   sudo apt-get install gpart gparted
2. Plug-in your USB hard-disk.
3. Open Gparted from the dash or from the command-line.
4. Select the hard-disk you wish to run data-rescue on, from the drop-down list on the right-top corner.
5. Go to 'Device' menu and click on 'Attempt Data Rescue'.

If that didn't help, here's an in-detail description, on how you can do it through the command-line using gpart:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery